# IIS rewrite rule not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite this:
domain.com/gallery/123123/name-of-the-image/

To display content from here: domain.com/gallery/showImage/name-of-the-image-123123

Here's my current code:

```
<rule name="Gallery - Single image">
    <match url="^gallery/([0-9])/([a-z-/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="gallery/showImage/{R:2}-{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

How should I alter the rewrite code to make it work?

Big thanks in advance

Comment: /([0-9])/ matches a single digit only, replace it with /([0-9]+)/ or /(\d+)/

Answer (score 0):

Your regex to match the URL should be:

```
^domain\.com\/gallery\/(\d+)\/([a-z-]+)\/?$
```

and the rewrite URL should be:

```
domain.com/gallery/showImage/{R:2}-{R:1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still getting the 404 error after these alterations. Are there anything else you can think of that might be wrong?

Comment: There is a possibility some other rule is already processing your URL before this one is being processed. Keep this rule on top of others that are less important. Also, try to change the type to "Redirect" instead of "Rewrite" so it may help you narrow what replacement is happening in the URL

Comment: My answer was too long here because I had to add code, not sure how to work with SO yet, but it's the message starting with "Thanks for the help".